# Real time web-app (socket-io) how to work with db views. Is it possible?

Tags: database, node.js, view, socket.io

We are trying to build a web application whose data updates in real-time. In order to do this we were thinking to use socket-io.

So the plan was:

1. A socket requests updates for a certain entity-type (say users) perhaps because it is displaying a list of users on the screen.
2. Check permissions of socket (by using the userId) and (assuming that it is allowed to see users) add it to a users room.
3. When another client changes the users view (Update, Insert or Delete) emit an event to the users room with the updated user attached.

However, we have run into a problem that we have not been able to solve:

How can we possibly know if another view has changed? Since our application pulls from views which are calculated objects, if a client updates viewA, it is totally possible that a row in viewB has changed as well (due to them sharing underlying tables). If there is a second client (socket) in the viewB room, it will not get its updated viewB entity and will go out of sync with the db.

Even if we stored in session a hash of views to underlying tables and used it to predict which views may have changed on update, we still wouldn't know which row specifically had changed?

Looking for ideas or approaches, all thoughts welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to consider the following: how many instances of Node JS will you be running in your production server? Each Node JS instance will have its own memory space and process and, as such, its own copy of your **user views**.  So, how do we sync them all?

`socket.io-redis` comes to the rescue for this, as all Node JS instances point to it. Then using `socket.io-emitter`, events can be emitted to clients from any instance.

```
var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 });
setInterval(function(){
  io.emit('time', new Date);
}, 5000);
```

If the example above, `host` and `port` is where Redis is located. Then, in the next line of code you can see io emitting the time to all clients every 5 seconds, regardless of what Node JS instance the clients are connected to. I use this architecture a lot and it works really well.

With this intro, now to your situation. I assume you're talking about a RDBMS, as you mentioned the words "view", "row", "insert", etc. in your question. If that's the case, one solution to your problem is what `socket.io` did with Redis: it "listens" for Redis events, in a pub / sub fashion. I don't know what RDBMS you're using, but one way to listen to DB events (without polling views) is through triggers, or by monitoring DB log files. Truth is, RDBMS's aren't that great for pub / sub events, but your use case requires exactly that. Is it possible to listen for events from your "calculated objects" (they'd publish messages)? If not, and you need to stick to RDBMS, you'll either resort to triggers / logs or you frequently poll the DB for table / view changes. Then, throught `socket.io` (most likely `socket.io-emitter`) you'd push these changes to your `socket.io-clients'.

With RDBMS there isn't an easy way to make things real time, you may have to settle for "near-real time". If real-time is absolutely required, you'd need a process to listen to view changes as mentioned above or, if possible, adopt a database with pub / sub capabilities.

I can't get into more details because I don't know enough about your desired architecture, but please feel free to add more details through comments and I'll do my best to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. The db is postgres. Why do you say that each of my nodeJS instances will have its own views? The db is on another server and they all point to it...

Comment: Some more specifics. We are using the Sequelize library as our ORM, it queries the pg db which is on another server. I mean I guess the question is two-fold, 1) from db's point of view: How is the db to know which rows in which views are being affected on an insert into some table? 2) Once the determines which rows in which views have changed, how is it to get the message back down to the server (I guess you are solving this with redis?) continued in next comment...

Comment: I thought about redis/pubsub but from what I understand, redis can easily have memory problems. I just don't understand how it is realistic to store an entire db in memory. Also, we like the idea of having a regular relational db/schema/data integrity tools to work with or are you saying to just store the views in redis? In which case how do we guarantee that redis won't go out of sync with the db?

Comment: Each Node JS instance will have its own processes and its own memory space. If your views are in memory as objects, that's what I meant "each Node JS will have its own view". Of course, if you have a monolith, with a single DB instance in the back-end, then you have a centralized view.

About your points. First, we need to reverse the direction of the information flow: it's from the DB to Node, not vice-versa unless you resort to polling. So: (continue on next comment)...

Comment: 1) It simply can't. All you can do is have the DB emit events (pub): "hey, I inserted a row here", then each of your Node JS instances (sub) will listen to that event and update themselves. You might be in luck: postgresql has some pub/sub capabilities (it's an amazing db). Check it out here: [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-notify.html) and here: [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-listen.html)

Comment: 2) I think your point #2 won't apply, as the information is flown the other way around now: NodeJS <-- DB, and not NodeJS --> DB. WIth that said, we can take Redis out of the picture; you won't need it. I just mentioned it because it has built-in pub/sub events. I used it a lot and I never had memory issues with it; however, with that said, Redis is for specific use cases, not necessarily to replace an entire RDBMS. I have some more thoughts to share with you, but I don't want to write a lot, I'd like to hear from you first.

Comment: Cool. I didn't realize that postgres had publish capabilities. That said, we still have a problem because sequelize is pulling from views. How can the database know when a view is updated? All it can know is when a table is updated...

Comment: I mean, the various clients (sockets) are pulling (via sequelize) from the db's views and displaying the entities. They are interested when those entities are updated (in fact, when that whole view is updated so that they can catch inserts). So, I can see how postgres could update a table and then publish "I inserted row X into tableA" but how could it publish "I inserted Y into viewA", how could it know how the changes it makes to tables affect its views?

Comment: "I inserted Y into view A" is now inside Node JS, and that also can be an inter-process communication, meaning from one Node JS instance to another. The simplest and best solution IMO is this phenomenal tool found [here](https://github.com/weixiyen/messenger.js).  Your case is more challenging than usual because it involves an RDBMS, and objects (view) in possibly several Node instances. But that's what also make it fun. Let me know if you find this tool, along with pg pub/sub useful! Please keep me posted!

Comment: I don't think I was clear. Basically I am wondering how postgres can possibly publish "I inserted Y into viewA". I don't think it can ever know what was inserted into a view. All it can know is what was inserted into a table.

Comment: I assume your "views" are held in memory as objects by Node JS instances. If this isn't correct, let me know. However, if that's the case, postgresql broadcasts inserts to all Node JS instances and *they* determine if they hold the view and check if it was updated. Then if the updated view needs to be broadcast to other Node instances you could then use messenger.js, for example. Sorry if I assumed some things about your architecture, as I was trying to give first some generic guidelines then go deeper into your particular requirements.

Comment: Right, so that isn't correct. Basically, we have one db server which stores tables, views etc. All node servers pull from it. The only thing running on db server is postgres. The question is how can postgres know which views have changed (and how they changed, i.e. which rows were inserted, updated or deleted) so it can broadcast changes to node?

Comment: Are your views [materialized](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)? If not, they're simply a SQL wrappers and there's no data stored in them. A couple of options: a) create a journal table which logs only the inserts in the DB you care about "I inserted Y". Then have this journal table broadcast this event to "view listeners" that will need to determine if "inserted Y" applies to them. In the end, it's the "view" job to determine if they care about  certain update or not. You can't have the "journal" or any other table having the burden (continued)

Comment: to do that. b) The other option is NOT to use DB views, but use Node JS instead to "act" as your views (my original assumption). I'm not sure if this is possible in your case, but that'd be better, that's where the logic belongs. When you start placing a lot of logic in the DB, you usually run into problems, as you are experiencing now. I strongly suggest (if possible) to move your view logic to Node. I hope this makes sense, please let's continue this dialog!

Comment: Why do you say that the views don't belong in the DB? My first instinct is that this is exactly where they belong. I mean the actual data model is normalized to such a degree that it does not resemble real-world objects. If we put the views on the server (which is an option if you convince me) the application developers would have to become familiar with the data model. The way we have it, just the data-architects/modelers need to know about the model. They expose a sensible model to the application developers on the server (continued)

Comment: In the sense that the "view-model" is what the server side developers are expecting. Additionally, we have all authorization logic in the db as well. This means that the server-side developers don't need to worry about security beyond authentication. They just attach the user-id to every action and let the db worry about providing the correct results. In other words the only data available to a user is data that is relevant to that user. We don't count on some developer who is putting together an end-point to implement that correctly (continued).

Comment: Implementing security would require that developer to be familiar with the normalized data model. Instead the security is built in to the database. All the developer needs to remember to do is send along the user id with the action.

Comment: I didn't mean to say literally move "db views" to Node, but code modules that'd replace the functionality of your db views. The challenge you face is that your "db views" need to act like listeners "I got updated" and all I'm saying this is tough, when views are essentially SQL wrappers. This SQL technology is old and limiting, working great for RDBMS, but to use with software... well, that's the problem we face here: it's just too limiting. If, and only if, you _could_ replace the logic with Node (I'm not saying you can/should do this because I haven't seen your views) ..cont'd

Comment: then you'd have better tools to deal with this problem. I worked for companies before where developers couldn't make such a choice, and maybe that's your case. So, if you must stay in the RDBMS world, then I don't see a way out besides using journal tables and triggers. Then your views (the SQL) would have to join with this journal table(s) and determine if they got updated or not. Node would then call View.A and the returning result set would contain the updates. When calling View.B, same thing. Then, what view(s) got updated? You'd need to query the journal table and place some ...

Comment: logic there (data) to determine what views got affected. With what you have now, it's not enough. All in all, you can choose between Node with sophisticated listeners (pub/sub) capabilities OR do this 100% in the RDBMS, in which case you need to design a journal table (or activity table, whatever name you prefer). I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you describe how I would go about building a module to replace a view (we are using sequelize as our ORM)?